# Can I say "I am not a native speaker in English" ? or just say "I am not a native speaker"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

A few years ago,  a German consultant came over to join our meeting in Taiwan, and we always speak local language occasionaly. The German consultant always remind us "Speak in English, please!" seriously.

Since that day , I used to say：

> "I am a native speaker in Chinese"
>
> "He is a native speaker in German"
>
> "I am not a native speaker in English"

German consultant however is not a native speaker in English either.

I would like to know if I can say:

> "I am not a native speaker in English" ?

or just say

> "I am not a native speaker" ?

or something else?

Furthermore, German consultant sometime emphasized in short:

> "In English , please!"

Is that okay to a native English speaker or not?

Comment: It depends on ***context***. Here on ELL it would be fine to omit "of/in English", since the relevant language is contextually implied.

Comment: I have revised my question with more information.  Could any moderator  reopen my question? Thanks.

Comment: I'll vote to reopen - but I'm not a mod, so it would require 4 others to agree. Note that if the specific language (that either is or isn't one's mother tongue) is NOT contextually obvious, *native speakers **of** English* tend to choose different phrasing anyway, rather than fret about which preposition to use...

Comment: I just searched Google NGrams for [a native speaker * XXX](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+native+speaker+*+English&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20native%20speaker%20of%20English%3B%2Cc0) with XXX = English, French, German, Russian. In each case there was only ONE result (but the word matching the "placefiller" * was always ***of***). There's no grammatical or syntactic argument against ***in*** though, so it would be a harsh critic indeed who told you it was somehow "wrong".

Comment: Imho it wouldn't be impossible for someone to say (truthfully!) *I'm a native speaker **for** English* in certain contexts. Unless some specific construction is sufficiently common as to have a clear-cut *idiomatically established* form, there's often a degree of flexibility in respect of preposition choice.

Comment: If an *actual* "native speaker of English" were in your German consultant's situation, they'd know perfectly well that "In English, please!" is just a shortened version of the imperative command/request *[Would you] **speak** in English, please?*  But in your context, the English language is just a "lingua franca", so it doesn't really matter how "grammatically" or "idiomatically" the non-native speakers speak, *so long as they are understood*. It's not a context where it's important to know exactly how native Anglophones might speak.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes , you are absolutely right.  I can understand what my German consultant means no doult. Just curious about the correct answer from a native English speaker.   Thanks for your comments.  Have a good day!

Comment: @FumbleFingers  The answer of this post make me more confused.  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/146856/making-friends-with-english-and-making-friends-in-english

Comment: All I can say about the answer you just linked to is that with no additional context to go on, the first interpretation of *make friends with English* that comes to mind for me is the one posted as a comment by stangdon (i.e. - treat the English language as a metaphorical "friend"). But so far as I can see, that interpretation never even occurred to the user who posted that answer. The bottom line is there's a lot of both ambiguity *and* flexibility about how prepositions are used in English, and I'm afraid you'll often find that you just have to learn things case by case (not by "rules").

Comment: @FumbleFingers    While I review the comments you gave above,  I found that you had already answered my question.   :D  “Would you speak in English, please?".  This is quite simillar to that answer of the post I linked above.  You are right , I need to learn things case by case especially for language.  Thank a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the preposition "of", not "in" as follows:

I am a native speaker of Russian.

I am not a native speaker of English.

Comment: How about "I am not a native English speaker" ?

Comment: @McMillanCheng, It's OK

Comment: *I am not a native English speaker* is, to me, more natural and it is what I would use if I were saying that.  To your original question, though, you can drop "English" if it's obvious you're talking about English, e.g. *Do you speak English?* -> *Yes, but I'm not a native speaker.*

Comment: German consultant sometime say "In English, Please!" in short. Is that okay for a native English speaker?