# ""Making friends with English."" and ""Making friends in English.""

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

What is the difference between ""Making friends with English."" and ""Making friends in English.""?

I want to say "use English to make friends",which one is better?

Comment: What difference between "with" and "in" have you found?

Comment: In my brain, ""with"" means ""use"" or " do things together with somebody "

Comment: "in" means in some circumstance ,or inside something .

sorry,I am not really good at English ,maybe it's hard to get what I mean.

Comment: The answer below was not visible when your question came before me. That answer and comment are clear, and should guide you.

Comment: Thank you . Maybe the problem is that I don't really know  how to use "with " and " in " as a precise way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Making friends *with* English" means that you use English as a means to make friends (the reason you made those friends is that you spoke English). "Making friends *in* English" means that you made a friend, and you spoke English to do so. "Using English to make friends" is a more elegant ("better") way to say "Making friends with English". The third option is probably the best.

Comment: "Making friends *with* English" could also be interpreted as "Making the English language into your friend".  I agree that your third option is the clearest of all.

Comment: That is the first time I know this kind of using , It's good learning to me.

Is it  mean  instil English into the head of friends?Just like brain washing?

Comment: To Daniel G , I appreciate your help  ,very helpful. and as your advice and knowledge ,I will use "using" directly to describe situation like that  .
.

But I  still have a little bit of confusion.Could you help me with making  some sentences besides making friends  to show the difference between in and with  ?

Comment: @Gary It's not an impossible interpretation, but one usually doesn't think of the phrase "to make friends" as such a unilateral action.

Comment: I'll help you, Gary: "He is in the room with me." "In" means inside the room; "with me" means we are together in the room.